# What are the advantages and disadvantages of using require vs using fs.readFile to get JSON from a file

Tags: node.js

If I'm using JSON data in a project is it better to use readFile like this:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var obj;
fs.readFile('file', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
  if (err) throw err;
  obj = JSON.parse(data);
});
```

or just use require

```
var config = require('./file.json');
```

I have tried finding performance comparisons but I couldn't find any. In this [post by FredKSchott](http://fredkschott.com/post/2014/06/require-and-the-module-system/) the author dives into the require function and it looks like it can improve performance by caching but it appears synchronous whereas fs.readFile is **asynchronous**

Comment: The fact that it's synchronous on first use would only matter if the first use happens during something time sensitive such as an http request. otherwise i can't see much reason to instead use readFile unless you want to be able to see changes to the file on future reads.

Comment: Take into consideration that if you decide to use require, the file will be loaded and cached until you restart the server. If you require it from another file, the cached version from memory will be used instead of reading the file again. On the other hand if you use fs.readFile the file will be read each time you use this method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two main differences:

1. `require()` caches the results so changes to the .json file will not be seen in subsequent reads of the JSON with `require()` unless the result is explicitly removed from the require cache.
2. `require()` is synchronous, `fs.readFile()` is asynchronous.  You could, of course, use `fs.readFileSync()` if you wanted synchronous behavior (but not sure why).

Other than those, you can pretty do it whichever way you want.

- If caching was a problem (e.g. you don't want caching), then I'd use `fs.readFile()`.
- If caching was a benefit, then I'd use `require()`.
- If I explicitly wanted async behavior because this was not being done just at startup, but was being done in a request handler, then I'd use `fs.readFile()` to preserve the asynchronous responsiveness of the server.
- Other than those two, if this code was running at startup, I'd use `require()` because it's just less code and is a behavior built into node.js.

Answer (score 0):

While it is true that `require()` is synchronous in nature, since all requires are, by convention, expected to resolve during the first tick, it's fine.

That is, you shouldn't use `require()` inside of a callback or as part of formulating a response, but using it for that first application boot is fine, because it only happens one time.

The advantage for require is that it is simpler, much more readable, and conveniently returns the object, already parsed by JavaScript.